# Is it possible to set a custom App Signature in my flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to implement an automatic OTP copy and fill in my flutter app. Most packages I have seen require that the app signature be added to the end of the sms.

Something like this (example sms):

**Your OTP is [OTP][App Signature]**

**Your OTP is 57123 kl+TryUPYz**

However, I was wondering if it was possible to manually customize my app signature. So instead of this random text that the user will see, they can see something more presentable, maybe like the app name instead, for example:

**Your OTP is 57123 RocknRoll**

Answer (score 0):

for generate app signature

```
keytool -exportcert -alias PlayDeploymentCert -keystore MyProductionKeys.keystore | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n com.example.myapp `cat` | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11
```

but this not give same signature that you want is depending on you app keystore files

Comment: it seems this might not be possible. Customizing app signature.